# Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix, let $B$ be an $n\times p$ matrix and let $C$ by a $p \times q$ matrix. Prove that $A(BC) = (AB)C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that I should use the $(i,j)$th entries of the LHS and RHS to prove this however I did it and it didn't work out for me. Could someone please help me out?

My workings were:

The $(i,j)$th entry of the LHS:
$$\sum_k a_{ik}(b_{kj}c_{kj})$$

The $(i,j)$th entry of the RHS:
$$\sum_ka_{ik}(b_{kj}c_{kj})$$

Then I multiplied out the brackets. However I dont know if it was okay to use $a_{ik}$ when computating the $(i,j)$th entry of the RHS or if I should have had $c_{ik}$ instead.

Comment: Show us what you did. It's a straightforward computation.

Comment: $$ {{\left[ \left( ab \right)c \right]}_{ij}}={{\left( ab \right)}_{ik}}{{c}_{kj}}=\left( {{a}_{il}}{{b}_{lk}} \right){{c}_{kj}} $$

Can you continue using the associativity of scalar multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

First, it should be noted that the $(i,j)$-entry of $A(BC)$ is 
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^na_{i\ell}\left( \sum_{k=1}^p b_{\ell k} c_{kj} \right)
$$
and the $(i,j)$-entry of $(AB)C$ is 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^p\left( \sum_{\ell=1}^na_{i\ell} b_{\ell k}\right)  c_{kj}. 
$$
You should be able to take it from here.